# why motherboard wires started to work as antennas in higher clock rates, these wires

Tags: cpu, motherboard, clockspeed

i read [this article](https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-a-cpu-works/2/) about CPU 
part of article say :

> As the processor clock signal became very high, one problem showed up. The motherboard where the processor is installed could not work using the same clock signal. If you look at a motherboard, you will see several tracks or paths. These tracks are wires that connect the several circuits of the computer. The problem is that with higher clock rates, these wires started to work as antennas, so the signal, instead of arriving at the other end of the wire, would simply vanish, being transmitted as radio waves.

but this don,t tell anything in depth about this problem
can anyone explain me why motherboard wires act as antennas in high CPU clock and make signal vanished?

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly tricky question...

The basic reason (in simple terms), is that any electric current creates an electromagnetic field around it. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction) Any electric current variation induces a variation in the electromagnetic field, which costs energy.

At low frequencies, these variations happen rarely enough that the lost energy is negligible compared to the total energy running through the wire, as the current flows and transports energy for a longer period of time for each transition.

At high frequencies, the energy lost to the magnetic field is greater (more transitions) At some point the loss is too significant, and the signal is no longer received correctly.

Also, then the total energy emitted into the air is sufficient to be captured by other wires. (In the same way that an electric current generates an electromagnetic field, an electromagnetic field generates a current)

There are also other reasons why higher frequencies are hard to achieve on a motherboard. For example, electricity only travels so fast (*speed of light*, if we neglect the propagation properties of the wires) and this can become significant when timings drop under a certain threshold. because the actual level of the signal is different on different places on the wire. In a CPU, the distance traveled by the current is smaller, so this problem is encountered at higher frequencies. There is also endpoint resonance to take into account, etc.